# javascript is not working properly in explorer

Tags: javascript

I'm doing my website in safari. it works we'll for that and in chrome too. but in explorer its not working properly. the alignments are upset, ajax file is not loading and some php codes (header: location....) also not working in explorer

```
    <form name="form_product" method="post" action="go.php">
            <input 
                    type="radio" 
                    name="go" 
                    value="<?php echo "{$row['code']}"; ?>"         
                    id="<?php echo "{$row['code']}";?>"
                    onChange="this.form.submit();">
            <label for="<?php echo "{$row['code']}"; ?>">
                    <img 
                            src="<?php echo"{$row['img_link']}"?>" 
                            alt="<?php echo"{$row['img_name']}"?>"
                            style=" height:500px; width:300px"/>
            </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be here:

```
onChange="this.form.submit();"
```

maybe it should be something like `this.parentNode.submit();`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My first problem starts here. when i click the image in the form, the action is in go.php page. From there it should get the value and load the appropriate page. your suggestion works for safari, but still not working for explorer. this is my site "abayatdubai.com"

Comment: The form is not submitting in explorer